# I WANT at least 3 uart in interrupt in stm32

Tags: stm32, uart

while I am using six UART in interrupt then my hardware is not working properly i.e hanging.

could you please tell me what should I do for this?

while I am using the polling method then it's ok but on interrupt, it's not working.

I am using call back function

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)  
{
  //check for global interrupt active or not
  if(huart->Instance==USART5) //for printer
  {
    if(Rx_data!=0x0D)
    {
      rx_button[Rx_indx++]=Rx_data;
    }

    if(Rx_data==0x0D)
    {
      if(rx_button[0]!=0)
      {
        for(uint8_t i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
          buffer[i]=rx_button[i];
        }
      }

      if(rx_button[0]==0)
      {
        for(uint8_t i=1;i<15;i++)
        {
          buffer[i-1]=rx_button[i];
        }
      }

      Rx_indx=0;
      for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
      {
        rx_button[i]=0;
      }

      if(huart->Instance==USART6)// from LCD TOUCH
      {
        if(Rx_data!=0x0D)
        {
          rx_button[Rx_indx++]=Rx_data;
        }

        if(Rx_data==0x0D)
        {
          if(rx_button[0]!=0)
          {
            for(uint8_t i=0;i<15;i++)
            {
              buffer[i]=rx_button[i];
            }
          }

          if(rx_button[0]==0)
          {
            for(uint8_t i=1;i<15;i++)
            {
              buffer[i-1]=rx_button[i];
            }
          }

          Rx_indx=0;

          for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
          {
            rx_button[i]=0;
          }
        }
      }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to EE. Please take time to improve your question. Properly format the code. Better describe what you want to achieve and where you are stuck (What is the thing with 3 and 6 UARTs? What is the polling method?). You might also want to consider to provide more code (your current code refers the many variables declared elsewhere)?

Comment: Najir, I did a little formatting & indenting of your code, and if that code is a copy-paste of your real code then I can't see how `if(huart->Instance==USART6)` will ever be true because it's inside the `if(huart->Instance==USART5)` block. `huart` cannot be both `USART5` and `USART6` at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much Brhans.
Could you please tell me what should I do that I can use 6 UART in INTERRUPT.
Do you have some examples? that I can understand
Thank You